Space group P4nc
I'm trying to understand space group diagrams and I have basics of symmorphic and non-symmorphic space groups and matrix calculation.
I don't know how to interpret the c in third place. How can I relate it to direction along the diagonals of the ab faces?
I imagined the c means a glide plane with translation along c and reflection respect to a plane which is parallel to c, but how can I relate this plane to the diagonal?
I think I make some confusion with tetragonal nomenclature of space groups, so a summary might be helpful.
